# can't submit form in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been working in a new  chrome extension, and i am Beginner 
I have a form with login details (username and password)
and i want to check username and password with database and move to another page or form in this extension.

popup file
    
    
    
     
    Local Storage Encoding
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Local Storage Security

LOGIN
    Username:
    Password:
     
      
    default user\password: admin\admin

and js file

```
function checkuser()
{
var x1, y1;
x1= document.getElementById("username").value;
y1= document.getElementById("password").value;
if(x1==="admin" && y1==="admin"){
        window.alert(x1);}
else{   
        }           
 }
```

i have 2 question
1- how can i do this??? because i try a lot, and i can't do this
2- what's the best way to store (safe and secure) database in chrome extension

note: this extension work client side only

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't way in client side to do security login!

The easiest way in javascript to store a data is localStorage.

The safest way is [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) because the user cann't easily change and delete the data - but he can!

There isn't a speciel way in chrome-extension to do this.

(I'm  sorry about my english)

Answer (score 1):

Local Database is the way. Jquery gives freedom to give you local databse for session or cache form.

further details: http://www.sitepoint.com/top-10-jquery-database-plugins/